# Trying to select with .Range( .Cells( #,#) ) won't work in VBA

Tags: vba, range, selection, cells

I'm trying to select a range of cells and I need to use LastRow as the variable that defines the last row of the selection. Here is my code (well the necessary part anyway, it's part of a large loop..):

```
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = FlowWkbs(f).Sheets(w).Cells(7,sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With FlowWkbs(f).Sheets(w)
        .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Normal_0to1"
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        .Cells(LastRow, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Select
        .Cells(LastRow, 7).Activate
    End With
```

I am getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" as an error on the line:

```
        .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Select
```

It's funny because it does fine with assigning `.Cells(LastRow,7)` to a value of `1`. But it can't handle the selection of `G2:G65335` (that happens to be my last row) In the form that I want it to be in. I need to have the `LastRow` variable change for each iteration of `FlowWkbs(f)` and `Sheets(w)` so I need to use the `Range(Cells(#%@%))` method as opposed to `Range("G2:G324")`

I've looked at a number of other questions/topics on here and they all suggest to add the Workbooks.Worksheets. prefix to the Range and Cells, but the With should take care of all that.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear how you'd ever get a value of 65335 using  `.End(xlToLeft).Column` - that max that can ever be is 16,384

Comment: @TimWilliams excel increase the row limit to 1048576, a while ago i think 2008

Comment: @HolmesIV - that's not relevant here: code uses `.Column`, not `.Row`

Comment: The Column thing was a typo, I copy and pasted the imput for my LastColumn variable instead of LastRow. In my actual code I used: LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Also I figured it out (see the answer below)

Answer (score 0):

You're finding the last column and putting the value in `LastRow`, then using that as the row argument to `.Cells`.  If you need the last row, do something like this:

```
With FlowWkbs(f).Sheets(w)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Normal_0to1"
    .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    .Cells(LastRow, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Select
    .Cells(LastRow, 7).Activate
End With
```

If you need to work with a range of *columns*, switch the argument order in your calls to `.Cells` (and rename the misleading variable).

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted the wrong variable definition for LastRow, the actual LastRow in my code did find the last row and not column. So the issue wasn't that I was getting the last column. Also, that really wouldn't have answered my question because the variable LastRow would have still had a number value and the same error would've shown up..

The problem was that the Worksheet that I was trying to run the Range.select on wasn't selected first. This is the corrected code (without the row/column typo):

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With FlowWkbs(f).Sheets(w)
    .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Normal_0to1"
    .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    .Cells(LastRow, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    .Select
    .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Select
    .Cells(LastRow, 7).Activate
End With
```

Voila!